# Writing array into bitmap c++

Tags: c++, bitmap

I have trouble with writing array into a bitmap again, so basically I read data from .bmp file where I get data of pixels and I want to make B and R = 0 so here it is my code:

```
int row_padded = ( Picture.biWidth*3 + 3) & (~3);
unsigned char* data = new unsigned char [row_padded];
unsigned char tmp;
 for(int i = 0; i < Picture.biHeight; i++)
{
    fread(data, sizeof(unsigned char), row_padded, plik);
    for(int j = 0; j < Picture.biWidth*3; j += 3)
    {
        data[j] = 0;
        data[j+2] = 0;

    }
}
```

Now when I have my B and R = 0 I want to save it again to the same file, so I am using:

```
for(int j = 0; j< Picture.biHeight; j++)
{
    fwrite(data,1,Picture.biWidth, f);
}
```

but nothing works.

Comment: You're only holding one scanline in memory at a time, so you'll have to seek and write it back out before reading the next line.  Otherwise you'll write many copies of the last row.

Comment: ok, so what you mean I need to use fseek to move to 'Offset' place, then start writing my file right? But what, I need to do it in a loop and every time it needs to back to Offset place? Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

`fwrite(data,1,Picture.biWidth, f)` must be `fwrite(data,1,row_padded, f)` no ? else only the first third of the bytes are written

note : by definition `sizeof(unsigned char)` is 1

Comment: doesn't work, im opening file like that:
 FILE* f = fopen( "test.bmp", "r+b" );

Comment: @kinket123 are you under Windows ? in that case you also need to add 'b' to open write file ( _"w+b"_ ). The size of the input and output files must be exactly the same, is it the case ?

Comment: There are several formats for the bmp files, are you sure the input file is in 24bits / 1 byte per color ?

Comment: yes im under windows, but if i change r+b to w+b it doesn't read data about this bmp file (bitmapfile header etc)

Comment: you cannot open in "w+b" to read, I just said that if you need to open to read in binary (`plik = fopen(<input bmp>, "r+b");` then you also need to open to write in binary (`f = fopen(<output bmp>, "w+b");`), read and write are symmetric